# Less but better — Should I delete this edit button?

Tags: web-app

I'm creating a web app, and I want it to be as simple as possible.
Users will enter data in my web app in a table, and then this data will be displayed to them in an other way.
What I am wondering is if I should keep the "Edit" button since the edition is made in the table view which also have a dedicated icon.
Here is a cropped screenshot of my web app showing the icons :
[image: The icons of my web app]

Comment: We cant give any feedback unless we see your entire web app since we will need to see how the edit button is being used in the table view

Comment: @MervinJohnsingh The table view isn't ready yet... but basically this will be a two column table.

Comment: Elements of a UI work together as part of a whole. It's hard to critique a part without the whole.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the screenshot and the short description you gave of your application I assume you want to give your users ability to enter into a 'Input/edit' mode and a 'view/review' mode.

I always try to rely on 'modes' only when it's absolutely necessary e.g. for sensitive actions to offer users a distraction-free UI.

If possible, try to give users ability to edit the table or the data in each cell by simply clicking on it (e.g. double click to edit the cell value). 
Consider the example of Google Spreadsheets in the Google docs suite. They allow a read-only mode, for users that don't have write privileges. But for those who can read/write, the data can be changed directly.